# How can I add a given amount of 2D vectors into a 3D vector?

Tags: c++, vector, maze

I am currently developing a maze generator and splitting it up into cells which I aim to add up to create a maze, and each cell is a 2d vector where classes are employed. How can I add all of the corresponding 2d vectors to a 3d vector to generate the maze? Below is the code I have been employing.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<char> > > maze::matrix (int rows, int columns, std::vector<std::vector<char> > cell)  {

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<char> > > maze;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        
        maze.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<char> >());

        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {

            maze.at(i).push_back(cell);

        }
    }

    return maze;

}
```

Comment: Why is a single cell a 2D vector? As for your problem, it would be useful to make concrete types for these things, or at least type aliases, e.g. `using Cell = std::vector<std::vector<char>>;`. Then you have `std::vector<Cell> maze;`. Does that help you see the problem?

Comment: *I am currently developing a maze generator and splitting it up into cells which I aim to add up to create a maze* -- Instead of explaining details of your maze generator, you could simply created a `main` program, consisting of a triply-nested vector, a doubly-nested vector, a single dimension vector, and played around with it to get it to work.  It makes no difference what type the single dimension vector is.  That way, you would have a [mcve], plus we could all see clearly what you are doing incorrectly.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<char> > cell` -- You passed one single 2D vector, not multiple 2D vectors.  So your description of wanting to add multiple 2D vectors to `maze` does not match up with what your function is doing.  What would make more sense is if `maze` were not a local variable, but some non-local variable that you were building up with 2D vectors.  So maybe you should start there -- design your program / function to match your specifications.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, in the program, that cell will be different each time, given that it is generated somewhere else that is irrelevant to this question. What I am trying to do here is to add and join all those cells based on the number of rows and columns desired

Comment: So why is `maze` local?  You are creating a brand new `maze` every time you call that function, and you are not adding to an exisiting maze vector.  That's the confusing part, and I wouldn't doubt this is why you're having issues with the code.  I could understand if you were passing `maze` as a reference to an existing maze, but you are not doing that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thank you for pointing that out; I just realized that issue and added it to the class' private elements. However, I still need help adding all those 2D vectors to the 3D maze vector

Comment: Add the edited code (do not change the original code in the post).

Comment: Create a new code block in the text edit window.

Answer (score 1):

First, as suggested, you should make aliases for the types, so that you can more clearly see the issue:

```
#include <vector>

// Create aliases
using Char1D = std::vector<char>;
using Char2D = std::vector<Char1D>;
using Char3D = std::vector<Char2D>;

int main()
{
  // Sample set of cells 
  Char2D cells = {{'x','y'},{'0','1'}};
  Char2D cells2 = {{'0','1'},{'x','y'}};

  // The maze to add the above cells
  Char3D maze;

 // Now add the cells to the maze
  maze.push_back(cells);
  maze.push_back(cells2);
}
```

That code adds 2 different `Char2D` cells to the `maze`.

The issue with your code is that you were basically calling `push_back` with the wrong types -- you were calling `maze[i].push_back`, but `maze[i]` is already a `Char2D`, so you were trying to `push_back` a `Char2D` into a `Char2D`.

More than likely, your code was not following your specification of adding 2D vectors to the 3D vector.

Answer (score 0):

Please also include the unexpected behavior you get. In this case, this code won't compile.

`maze` is a `vector<vector<vector<char>>>` i.e. 3D vector

`maze.at(i)` is a `vector<vector<char>>` i.e. 2D vector

You are trying to push_back(cell), where cell is a 2D vector.std::vector::push_back takes an element of the vector, so for a 2D vector it takes a 1D vector i.e. `maze.at(i).push_back(std::vector<char>{})`.

Comment: `maze.at(i).push_back(std::vector<char>{}).` could simply be: `maze.at(i).push_back({});`

Comment: Is this really an answer or is it a comment? I can't really tell, but it starts off with asking for more details, which usually should be a comment instead of an answer.